# IF statement in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a simple spreadsheet that lists a date in one of three columns C,D, or E

The following formula will validate which column has the data.

```
=IF(OR(C4>0,D4>0,E4>0),1,0)
```

Can you help me replace the TRUE value as the month of year for the cell which has a date value?

Comment: The 1 is the true value, just point it at the cell you want, so replace it with A1 or C5 etc! It's hard to understand the question, what cell contains month and year?

Comment: @DaveRook I think he his saying the value he is looking for could be either in c4 or d4 or e4 and he wants that in the result.

Comment: You should not test for OR() because that gives you only true/false. Use HLOOKUP to find the cell that contains the data, then extract the month from that cell. Anyone cares to make a full answer of this (with the exact formula), be my guest.

Answer (score 3):

There's more than 1 way to do this. I'm assuming there's only one date per row (as you mentioned) & that they're not in TEXT format.

---

**Method 1**

1. Enter the ff formula.

   `=IF(OR(C4>0,D4>0,E4>0),SUM(C4:E4),0)`
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, click Custom & enter `mmmm yyyy` (or `mmmm` if you only want the month) in the field. Click OK.

Or if you want the month/year in text, change the formula to:

```
=IF(OR(C4>0,D4>0,E4>0),TEXT(SUM(C4:E4),"mmm yyyy"),0)
```

and do away with Step 2.

---

**Method 2**

Condense your formula. Since you only have to check if a date value is present, do away with the IF statement & just SUM the cells or use MAX. If they're empty, you'll get a 0 anyway.

```
=SUM(C4:E4)
```

or

```
=MAX(C4:E4)
```

And then change the number format<sup>**[1]**</sup> to any of the following:

- `mmmm;0;0`
- `mmmm yyyy;0;0`
- `mmm;0;0`
- `mmm yyyy;0;0`

---

**Method 3**

Using HLOOKUP

```
=IF(OR(C4>0,D4>0,E4>0),HLOOKUP(MAX(C4:E4),C4:E4,1,FALSE),0)
```

or if you're running MS Excel 2007 & above:

```
=IFERROR(HLOOKUP(MAX(C4:E4),C4:E4,1,FALSE),0)
```

Don't forget to change the number format accordingly (see step 2 of method 1).

If you want the output in text format, enclose the formulas in the TEXT function, like so:

```
=IF(OR(C4>0,D4>0,E4>0),TEXT(HLOOKUP(MAX(C4:E4),C4:E4,1,FALSE),"mmmm yyyy"),0)
```

or

```
=IFERROR(TEXT(HLOOKUP(MAX(C4:E4),C4:E4,1,FALSE),"mmmm yyyy"),0)
```

---

<sup>**[1]**</sup> <sup>*For more info on number formats: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/number-format-codes-HP005198679.aspx*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Quickly hacked solution. Use nested IF's:

```
=IF(C4>0,C4,IF(D4>0,D4,IF(E4>0,E4,0)))
```

Probably a better way to do this with a LOOKUP function but don't have time to test it out right now.

Answer (score 1):

This version will give you 0 if all 3 cells are empty otherwise it gives you the month number of the last date (positionally)

`=IF(COUNT(C4:E4),MONTH(LOOKUP(10^7,C4:E4)),0)`

Not really necessary for 3 cells but can be extended for any size range